# sns.countplot, multiple df columns in same plot

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns of Facebook posts with columns year, day, likes, comments etc.
I want to produce a single countplot having some of those columns, let's say Picture, Video, Link with same y axis. Each one having 0 or 1 for No/Yes.
I have only achieved to produce the below chart, but the problem is that they have different y axis.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,5)
sns.countplot(df['Picture'], ax=ax[0])
sns.countplot(df['Video'], ax=ax[1])
sns.countplot(df['Youtube'], ax=ax[2])
sns.countplot(df['Link'], ax=ax[3])
sns.countplot(df['Teaser'], ax=ax[4])
```

I don't mind having multiple plots side by side, but I want the same axis for them.
I wonder also, if possible to have only one graph and keep only the yes (1) values.

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1):

`plt.subplots()` has an argument `sharey` which defaults to `False` but if set to `True` shares the y-axis across the other axes

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,5,sharey=True)
```